# How do I use pylab to plot a phase plane for pendulum motion?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ode

I have code that will work for plotting the following predator prey model:

> dx/dt = x − xy, dy/dt = −y + xy

```
from pylab import *
xvalues, yvalues = meshgrid(arange(0, 3, 0.1), arange(0, 3, 0.1))
xdot = xvalues - xvalues * yvalues
ydot = - yvalues + xvalues * yvalues
streamplot(xvalues, yvalues, xdot, ydot)
show()
```

But I am not sure how to use these functions to draw a phase plane (using streamplot) to model pendulum motion, defined as

> d^2θ/dt^2 = (−g/L)sin(θ)

How can I implement this model to produce a phase plane using matplotlib and pylab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it the same way, first transform it into a first order system

```
thetadot = omega
omegadot = -g/L*sin(theta)
```

rename `theta, omega` to `x,y` for shortness and then proceed as before:

```
g,L = 1,1
xvalues, yvalues = meshgrid(arange(-8, 8, 0.1), arange(-3, 3, 0.1))
xdot = yvalues
ydot = -g/L*sin(xvalues)
streamplot(xvalues, yvalues, xdot, ydot)
grid(); show()
```

which gives the usual phase portrait

[image]